# Ajax post success function returning both success and error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Okay so I am trying to get ajax to post to my php file, lookup a mysql field and if it exists echo 'clientsuccess' otherwise echo 'Client already exists' 
but on success function it returns both values despite the fact that they're in an php if statement.
I am quite possibly missing something incredibly simply, but any help is greatly appreciated.

PHP:

```
    <?php 
session_start();
$clientArray = $_POST['clientArray'];

$clientArray = explode(',', $clientArray);
$count = 0;


foreach($clientArray as $clientField) 
{

trim($clientField);
if(empty($clientField)) {
$clientField = '-'; 
}

}




$con = mysql_connect("localhost",$_SESSION['MysqlUser'],$_SESSION['MysqlPass']);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect with '.$_SESSION['MysqlUser'].mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("smeinsti_SPW_Inventory", $con);

$checkclient = mysql_query("SELECT ClientName FROM Clients WHERE ClientName = '".$clientArray[0]."'", $con);

if(mysql_num_rows($checkclient)==0)
{

$sql="INSERT INTO Clients (`ClientName`, `PhoneNumber`, `Email`, `Address`, `OrderDate`)
VALUES
('$clientArray[0]', '$clientArray[1]', '$clientArray[2]', '$clientArray[3]', CURDATE())";


$clientArray[0] = $_SESSION['ClientName'];
echo "clientsuccess";



} else {
echo 'Client already exists';   
}


?>
```

JS:

```
    function NextPage()
{
var ClientData = [];

$('form#order-form.create input[type=text]').each(function() {

ClientData += $(this).val() + ',';

})

alert(ClientData);

var parameters = {
clientArray: ClientData
};

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
async:false,
url: "write_client.php",
data: parameters,
success: function(result){       
var res=result;
if(res = 'clientsuccess') {
window.location = 'admin.php?id=7';
} else {
alert('Client already exists');
}
}
}); 







}
```

Comment: how are you saying it is returning both

Comment: Hey Did you alert result within success function of jQuery-Ajax?

Comment: Correct this: `if(res = 'clientsuccess')`. That's an assigment, not a comparison, you should use `==`

Comment: change if(res = 'clientsuccess') to if(res == 'clientsuccess'),

Answer (score 1):

Your condition Equal symbol is not correct! Put '=='

```
    if(res == 'clientsuccess') { //Double Equal to
    window.location = 'admin.php?id=7';
    } else {
    alert('Client already exists');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_num_rows` returns the number of selected rows and not the fields of a certain row. Use `mysql_fetch_row` to fetch the row you have selected with your query:

You could also use mysql_result to fetch a row and get a certain field:

$client exist = mysql_result($checkclient, 0, 0);
This fetches the first row (zero based) and returns the first field (zero based).